# Python format a csv file to one line

Tags: python, csv

Having trouble formatting a cvs into one line with a comma after the first set of text is grabbed from a website and then the price.  What I am trying to do is have the product info and the price on one line separated by a comma after the product info so it can be imported into an Excel spreadsheet.  Any clues?  thanks

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv

b6 = open('sears.csv', 'w', newline='') 
a6 = csv.writer(b6,delimiter=',')

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get("http://www.sears.ca/catalog/appliances-fridges-freezers-refrigerators-top-freezer-en-wp-836#facet:&productBeginIndex:0&orderBy:&pageView:grid&minPrice:&maxPrice:&pageSize:100&").text)

g6_data = soup.select("div.product_name a")
p6_data = soup.select("div.product_price")

for g6, p6 in zip(g6_data, p6_data):
    c6 = (g6.text, p6.text)
    print(g6.text, p6.text)
    a6.writerow(c6)

b6.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Your request is ok, the filtering with `BeautifulSoup` not.

```
import requests
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get("http://www.sears.ca/catalog/appliances-fridges-freezers-refrigerators-top-freezer-en-wp-836#facet:&productBeginIndex:0&orderBy:&pageView:grid&minPrice:&maxPrice:&pageSize:100&").text)

g_descrs = [i.find("a").text for i in soup.findAll("div", {"class": "product_name", "itemprop": True})]
g_prices = [i.find("input").get('value') for i in soup.findAll("div", {"class": "product_price"})]

rows = map(lambda x: '%s;%s' % x, zip(g_descrs, g_prices))

with open('./result.csv', 'w') as result:
    for row in rows:
        result.write(row)
```

Comment: Sorry, I actually don't get any content that is displayed with this.

Comment: I have posted my entire code.  I am using Python 3.5 if that matters.  Still shows up with nothing

Comment: Haven't you changed the url?

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean?

Comment: The url is about fridges. Haven't you changed for some other category or other shop?

Comment: Some URL's are working great with being able to be put all on one line.  Its this URL thats giving me problems and I am not sure why.